# Typerror while calling a function using remote (Electron.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, typeerror, developer-tools

This is a simplified version of my application.

I am creating an application in electron that executes a javascript script that writes a hello world in the console when opened, This is the index.js file, where the window is created, as well as the function that sends the hello world is defined:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

require("./scripts/database")

const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

function hello() {
    console.log('Hello World');
}

let mainWindow;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {})
}

app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false;
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 576,
        width: 1024,

        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // mainWindow.setMenu(null);

})

module.exports = { 
    hello
}
```

This is the body of the index.html:

```
<body class="body">
    <section class="box">

     

        <div class="button-box">
            <button id="L_VALIDATION">button1</button>
        </div>
        
    </section>

    <script src="./scripts/hello-world.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the file where the function is called using remote:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const index = remote.require('../index')

index.hello()
```

Now this all seems to be fine, but when I run the file, I keep getting this error in the Developer Tools window:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'require')
    at hello-world.js:5:22
```

I already checked the file paths, in case that's the problem, but that didn't seem to be the problem.